# PHP- file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using the following API for getting the country code using IP

```
http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $IP
```

Example: on **Localhost**

```
$IP = '202.71.158.30';

//pass the ip as a parameter for follow URL it will return the country

$country_code = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $IP);
```

and its working fine here and showing the country code.

But it showing error on **Server**

Example:

```
$IP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$country_code = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $IP);
```

Showing following error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=101.63.xx.xxx)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection
>   refused in /srv/disk4/1322145/www/servername.in/app/header.php
>   on line 12

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Probably this has little to do with PHP and more with network restrictions. Try dumping `$http_response_header ` after `file_get_contents` to get more info about why it failed.

Comment: Make sure that you can open a url with fopen. See: http://php.net/file_get_contents#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-notes

Comment: @MarcellFülöp : But its working on localhost only the error showing on server. So is it the issue of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp : var_dump($country_code); showing bool(false)

Comment: I meant `$http_response_header`. This variable gets populated by PHP when `file_get_contents` is used with the HTTP wrapper and might give useful information about the HTTP request.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: you mean var_dump($http_response_header); right?

Comment: Yes. That should be an array, each element is a line of the response headers of the resulting HTTP response.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: Its showing NULL

Comment: @MarcellFülöp : `$country_code = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $ip);
var_dump($http_response_header);`

Comment: I expected that. There's no response, because the request didn't make through to the server. Check if allow URL fopen is on in the given PHP setup, and try `wget -d` from a terminal. That should give you more info about why it cannot connect to that server.

Comment: Try `wget -d -O /dev/null "http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=[an IP]"` and see the output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use CURL in place of file_get_contents()

```
<?php
    $IP = '202.71.158.30'; 
    $runfile = 'http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $IP;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $runfile);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch); 

    echo $content;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use curl method instead of **file_get_contents()**

It does not work on localhost at google.com. Instead use other engine or use curl below:

Make a function or use inside the same function:

I prefer it to use in a function to avoid repetition in future.

```
$IP = '202.71.158.30';
$country_code = file_get_contents_fun('http://api.hostip.info/country.php? 
ip='.$IP);
public function file_get_contents_fun($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
    $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch); 
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some servers do not permit accessing through IP address in your request.
You can use `CURL` to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `Fail2Ban` extension in Plesk suddenly started IP-blocking the server that did the `file_get_contents()` requests. This is probably not going to be the issue, but I just wanted you to be aware of such a possibility.

Comment: Spent the past 5 hours fighting with this thing.
This helped me. My server was banning itself on postfix! and it was killing the file_get_contents() response.

Comment: OMG!!!! I just spent a whole day trying to fix this. Your comment fixed it! Thank You. Saved me so much work. I thought I would have to re-code using cURL. Was working for 12 months then all of a sudden stopped. Fail2Ban was the culprit. Locked out the host server. Thank You again.

Answer (score 1):

add optional parameter in file_get_contents using stream_context_create function to open stream connection valid.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => ['protocol_version' => '1.1'],
]);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```