# file_get_contents is not working on server but working on localhost and allow_url_fopen is also on

Tags: php, url

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://$dns:$port/panel_api.php?username=$username&password=$password"), true);
```

The code is working on localhost but it's not working on server and it's showing " failed to open stream: Connection refused" while the "allow_url_fopen" is also on in server. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835274/php-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-connection-refused)

Comment: It seems that the remote server refuses the connection. Echo the complete URL and try to open this URL in your Browser. Does it work?

Comment: Do you have full control on your server ? can you check this variable in your php.ini file `allow_url_fopen` ?

Comment: @Arno yes it's working in browser. But don't know why it's not working on server while allow_url_fopen is also on in server.

Comment: I would suggest to try: 1. Using a hard coded string literal instead of variables. Just to make sure that the URL is correct. 2. Use another server within the URL - just for checking if the problem is on your php server or on the remote server.