# How to get data from REST API in CI Conroller?

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter

I've an API source and want to proccess it in my controller.

```
$user    = "myuser";
$pass    = "mypass";

$url     = "http://myurlforapi/StockSummary?userid='5'";
            
//$url   = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/132/";        
    
    $opts    = array(
            'http'  => array(
                        'method'    => "GET",
                        'header'    => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$user:$pass")                 
      )
    );
    
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    
    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $data= file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    
    print($data);
```

When I change the URL to the pokeapi.co, the data is displayed. But, when I use the myurlforapi no data is displayed. Do I miss something? or there is some configuration to do in my domain?

Update:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://myurlforapi/StockSummary?userid=5): failed to open stream: Connection refused

Filename: backend/Dashboard.php

Line Number: 51

Backtrace:

File: /home/u9354272/public_html/xxx/modules/dashboard/controllers/backend/Dashboard.php
Line: 51
Function: file_get_contents

File: /home/u9354272/public_html/xxx/index.php
Line: 339
Function: require_once
```

Note: When I use Postman, It's working. When I use it in my webhost, it's not working

Comment: maybe it's because of the apostrophes in your url? Try replacing them with `%27` or even better change your api so it take the call without apostrophes like so `http://myurlforapi/StockSummary?userid=5`

Comment: unfortunately it's not working

Comment: what do you get if you type in your API URL in Browser?

Comment: Some error text. Because user need to have auth. I've added some error response.

Comment: Please check latest update

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835274/php-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing your credentials correctly to the base64 encode function. Change this

```
$opts    = array(
        'http'  => array(
                    'method'    => "GET",
                    'header'    => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$user:$pass")                 
  )
);
```

to this

```
$opts    = array(
        'http'  => array(
                    'method'    => "GET",
                    'header'    => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($user . ':' . $pass)                 
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, the error log is the same. I contact the api developer and he said no request is sent to `http://myurlforapi`